# Reset all droppables to allow for draggables, after moving an object using .css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

So I have multiple draggables and multiple droppables. When all the droppables have a draggable in them, it runs a function and allows the user to reset the page. At the minute, this just uses the jQuery .css function to change the top and left CSS. How can I also make the droppable fields droppable again?

I.e. I want a for loop to use $(this) on each droppable.

```
$('.planets').draggable({
    opacity: .4,
    create: function(){$(this).data('position',$(this).position())},
    cursorAt:{left:15},
    cursor:'move',
    start:function(){$(this).stop(true,true)},
    revert : 'invalid'
});

$('.targets').droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('dropped-highlight')){
        $( this ).addClass( "dropped-highlight" );
        $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);
    }
  },
  out: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.planets');
    $(this).removeClass( "dropped-highlight" );
  }
});
```

Then there's a different function which changes the top and left of the draggable objects if they click the reset button.

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: I've updated it with the code, sorry I was trying to make some edits and forgot to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code it looks like you're only using the presence of the 'dropped-highlight' class to indicate that one of the planets has been dropped on a target.

You should just be able to remove that class from each of the targets to re-enable their 'droppable' status:

```
$('.targets').removeClass('dropped-highlight');
```

Comment: There's also this line in drop: `$(this).droppable('option', 'accept', ui.draggable);` and this line in out: `$(this).droppable('option', 'accept', '.planets');` This is what stops them actually being put back in to the droppables.